# javascript closures and prototypes

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, prototype

I thought I have understood the idee of closures, but the following code
behaves surprisingly for me:

```
function A(x)
{
  this.getX1 = function () { return x; }
  A.prototype.getX2 = function () { return x; }
}
var a1 = new A(1);
var a2 = new A(2);
console.log ('a1.getX1()=%d', a1.getX1 ()); // 1
console.log ('a2.getX1()=%d', a2.getX1 ()); // 2
console.log ('a1.getX2()=%d', a1.getX2 ()); // 2 ???
console.log ('a2.getX2()=%d', a2.getX2 ()); // 2
```

I could understand if prototype methods behave differently from
instance methods, but this looks like x has become a static variable.
Changing the order of calls does not change results.

Answer (score 4):

When you change the `prototype` you're changing the `function` for **all** instances of the given class, *including those that already exist*.

Therefore when you call...

```
A.prototype.getX2 = function () { return x; }
```

You're setting that for the existing `a1` instance of `A`. So effectively you're ending up with the following pseudo code:

```
<all instances of A>.getX2 = function () {
    return <latest value of x passed to A constructor>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The static member here is `A.prototype.getX2`. The second call to `A.prototype.getX2 = function () { return x; }` (due to `var a2 = new A(2);`) replaces the first one. To understand it you can reverse the order of instantiations:

```
var a2 = new A(2);
var a1 = new A(1);
```

Then you'll have:

```
a1.getX1()=1
a2.getX1()=2
a1.getX2()=1
a2.getX2()=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining getX2 twice, each time you create a new A. The result for that function will always be the last X. Considering rewriting your code like this:

```
function A(x) {

    this.x = x;
    this.getX1 = function() {
        return this.x;
    }
}
A.prototype.getX2 = function() {
    return this.x;
}
var a1 = new A(1);
var a2 = new A(2);
console.log('a1.getX1()=%d', a1.getX1()); // 1
console.log('a2.getX1()=%d', a2.getX1()); // 2
console.log('a1.getX2()=%d', a1.getX2()); // 1
console.log('a2.getX2()=%d', a2.getX2()); // 2​​​
```

This way, you only define getX2 once and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have written

```
function A(x)
{
  this.getX1 = function () { return x; }
  A.prototype.getX2 = function () { return x; }
}
```

This constructor overwrites `A.prototype.getX2` each time.

So first

```
var a1 = new A(1); // This invokes A and adds a function `getX2` to the prototype of `A`which returns `x` that is `1`

var a2 = new A(2); // This invokes A and overwrites the function `getX2` in the prototype of `A` with a function which returns `x` that is `2` now.
```

So it should be like this

```
function A(x)
{
  this.getX1 = function () { return x; }
}

A.prototype.getX2 = function () { return this.getX1(); }
```